# Смена background-image по скроллу

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброго времени суток.
Такая задача: необходимо дважды сменить значение `background-image`.
Первый раз - при начале скроллинга скрытой части страницы.
Второй раз - при скроллинге дальше `100vh`, то есть, приблизительно с третьей картинки.

[Страница здесь](http://mysolaris.xyz/slide1.html)

Как это сделать правильно? Сделанный мной корявый вариант работает некорректно. При отводе курсора от блока с картинкой появляется "второе" изображение.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.sub').css('opacity', 0);
  $('.all').css('opacity', 0);
});

$('.object-container').on('wheel', function(event) {

  // deltaY obviously records vertical scroll, deltaX and deltaZ exist too
  if (event.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
    $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/roof-after.png")');
    $('.all').css('opacity', 1);
    // wheeled up
  } else {
    $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/roof-after.png")');
    $('.all').css('opacity', 1);
    // wheeled down
  }
});

$('.third').mousemove(function() {
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.fourth').mousemove(function() {
  $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.fifth').mousemove(function() {
  $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.sixth').mousemove(function() {
  $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.seventh').mousemove(function() {
  $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.eigth').mousemove(function() {
  $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.nineth').mousemove(function() {
  $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.tenth').mousemove(function() {
  $('.slider').css('background-image', 'url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/black.png")');
  $('.slider_content').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.first').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.one').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.first').mouseout(function() {
  $('.one').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.one').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.one').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.one').mouseout(function() {
  $('.one').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.second').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.two').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.second').mouseout(function() {
  $('.two').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.two').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.two').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.two').mouseout(function() {
  $('.two').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.third').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.three').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.third').mouseout(function() {
  $('.three').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.three').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.three').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.three').mouseout(function() {
  $('.three').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.fourth').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.four').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.fourth').mouseout(function() {
  $('.four').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.four').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.four').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.four').mouseout(function() {
  $('.four').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.fifth').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.five').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.fifth').mouseout(function() {
  $('.five').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.five').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.five').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.five').mouseout(function() {
  $('.five').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.sixth').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.six').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.sixth').mouseout(function() {
  $('.six').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.six').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.six').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.six').mouseout(function() {
  $('.six').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.seventh').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.seven').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.seventh').mouseout(function() {
  $('.seven').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.seven').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.seven').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.seven').mouseout(function() {
  $('.seven').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.eigth').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.eight').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.eigth').mouseout(function() {
  $('.eight').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.eight').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.eight').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.eight').mouseout(function() {
  $('.eight').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.nineth').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.nine').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.nineth').mouseout(function() {
  $('.nine').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.nine').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.nine').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.nine').mouseout(function() {
  $('.nine').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.tenth').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.ten').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.tenth').mouseout(function() {
  $('.ten').css('opacity', 0);
});
$('.ten').mouseenter(function() {
  $('.ten').css('opacity', 1);
});
$('.ten').mouseout(function() {
  $('.ten').css('opacity', 0);
});
```

```css
  @font-face {
  font-family: Adineue;
  src: url("../fonts/adineue.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: ABold;
  src: url("../fonts/adineue-bold.ttf");
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.roof {
  color: #e64e4e;
}

.fasad {
  color: #f7a550;
}

.design {
  color: #fedd32;
}

.industry {
  color: #51b9f1;
}

.eco {
  color: #70ca57;
}

.stone {
  color: #956ccc;
}

.slider {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/roof-main.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider-content {
  height: 100vh;
  color: #fff;
}

.slider_content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 3vw;
}

.slider_content span {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.slider-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: baseline;
  margin-top: 33vh;
}

.slider-text h1 {
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.slider-text span {
  color: #e64e4e;
  font-family: 'ABold';
  font-size: 1.3em;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.slider-text p {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 0.825em;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.btn-roof {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: 21vh;
}

.btn-roof:hover {
  transform: rotate(-360deg);
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.hr {
  color: #e64e4e;
  background-color: #e64e4e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  margin-top: 7vh;
}

.object-container {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.all {
  margin-top: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 420%;
}

.for-all {
  width: 36vw;
  height: 26.35vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.sub {
  width: 36vw;
  height: 7.05vh;
  margin-bottom: 8vh;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 7.05vh;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 'Adineue';
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11);
}

.first {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/ruukki.png");
}

.second {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/cheker.png");
}

.third {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/bitum.png");
}

.fourth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/elems.png");
}

.fifth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/falz.png");
}

.sixth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/gidro.png");
}

.seventh {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/mansard.png");
}

.eigth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/metalo.png");
}

.nineth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/samorez.png");
}

.tenth {
  background-image: url("http://mysolaris.xyz/images/vodostok.png");
}

.right-side {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5v 5;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 33px;
  height: 33px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 33px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.149);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pure-g">
  <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1 pure-u-md-11-12">
    <div class="slider pure-g">
      <div class="slider-content pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">
        <div class="slider_content">
          <span>01</span>
          <div class="slider-text">
            <h1>Rofas <span>Roof</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis </p>
          </div>
          <a href="index.html" class="btn-roof"><i class="fa fa-undo fa-lg fa-rotate-90" style="color:#e64e4e"></i></a>
          <div class="hr"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider-right pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">
        <div class="object-container">
          <div class="all">
            <div class="for-all first"></div>
            <div class="sub one">Модульная металлочерепица Ruukki</div>
            <div class="for-all second"></div>
            <div class="sub two">Rofas Cheker</div>
            <div class="for-all third"></div>
            <div class="sub three">Битумная черепица</div>
            <div class="for-all fourth"></div>
            <div class="sub four">Элементы безопасности кровли</div>
            <div class="for-all fifth"></div>
            <div class="sub five">Фальцевая кровля</div>
            <div class="for-all sixth"></div>
            <div class="sub six">Гидро- тепло-пароизоляция</div>
            <div class="for-all seventh"></div>
            <div class="sub seven">Мансардные окна</div>
            <div class="for-all eigth"></div>
            <div class="sub eight">Металлочерепица</div>
            <div class="for-all nineth"></div>
            <div class="sub nine">Саморезы для крепления</div>
            <div class="for-all tenth"></div>
            <div class="sub ten">Водосточные системы</div>
          </div>
          <div class="right-side">
            <a href="index.html" class="btn"><img src="icons/return.png"></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" style="margin-top: 10vh"><img src="icons/speaker.png"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

событие `mouseout` и `mouseenter` не очень подходят для решение этой задачи, так как они срабатывает тогда когда курсор мышки находится над элементом или уходит с него. Вам надо смотреть в сторону `.scrollTop()` - получает значение отступа прокрутки сверху и `.offset().top` получаем значение отступа от начала стр. до элемента. `scrolTop()` пихаем в функцию, а саму функцию вешаем к обработчику .scroll(). Примерно выглядит так:

```
var margBlock_1 = $('.block_1').offset().top

function myScroll() {
  winScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop()
  if (winScrollTop < margBlock_1) {
   //тут пишем css свойство на смену background'a
  }
}
```

Функцию mySCroll() вешаем на обработчик событие scroll

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    myScroll();
})
```

как-то так...